# Are fprintf and fscanf reentrant when using different file handles

Tags: multithreading, printf, scanf, reentrancy

Can I have 2 threads in the same process calling fprintf or fscanf at the same time?

One stream is written to by the first thread and is read by the second thread and the other  stream is read by the first thread and is written to by the second thread. So, I don't have a situation of simultaneous writes or simultaneous reads to the same stream.

If the answer is no - Do I have an reentrant alternative in the printf/scanf family?

This questions follows some comments in: [Thread communication via printf and scanf (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527601/thread-communication-via-printf-and-scanf-linux)

Comment: Deadlock is possible.  Both threads reading, waiting for the other thread to write.

Comment: thread-safe != reentrant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are thread-safe. See http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html